# Campos de formularios que no funcionan en teléfono

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Tengo un formulario que funciona bien, pero en el móvil sólo el primer campo aparece activado y los demás no.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<div id="wrapper" class="container">
  <form id="form1" name="formbusvet" action="php/busvet.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="pnombre">Primer Nombre</label>
          <input name="pnombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Nombre" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="snombre">Segundo Nombre</label>
          <input name="snombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundo Nombre" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="papellido">Primer Apellido</label>
          <input name="papellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Apellido" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="sapellido">Segundo Apellido</label>
          <input name="sapellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundo Apellido" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="clase">Clase</label>
          <input name="clase" class="form-control" placeholder="Clase" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="batalla">Batalla</label>
          <input name="batalla" class="form-control" placeholder="Batalla" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <label class="control-label" for="division">Divisi&oacute;n</label>
          <input name="division" class="form-control" placeholder="Divisi&oacute;n" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <label class="control-label" for="brigada">Brigada</label>
          <input name="brigada" class="form-control" placeholder="Brigada" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="unidad">Unidad</label>
          <input name="unidad" class="form-control" placeholder="Unidad" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="batallon">Batall&oacute;n</label>
          <input name="batallon" class="form-control" placeholder="Batall&oacute;n" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="compagnia">Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a</label>
          <input name="compagnia" class="form-control" placeholder="Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:15px">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Buscar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola ,a qué te refieres con activado? Puedes agregar una foto del resultado que obtienes para poder ayudarte por favor

Comment: Podrías subir también el código CSS? Seguramente tengas algún elemento que ocupe más de lo debido, impidiendo que desde la vista de móvil se pueda hacer click en algunos inputs

Comment: Uso bootstrap 3.7, en ese formulario no hay css de mi autoria.

Answer (score 5):

Tienes la siguiente línea en tu formulario que te está generando el conflicto:

```
<div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</div>
```

Se está superponiendo sobre el primer contenedor con clase `.form-group`. No sé cual sea la utilidad de este campo si está vacío.

Adicional, justo debajo en tu código vuelves a llamar un `.col-md-12` en un segundo `.form-group`, esto no es necesario y por tanto debes quitar esta clase.

Puedes observar este comportamiento si utilizas el inspector de elementos:

[image: inspector de elementos]

Corrigiendo esto ya puedes esribir en los `input` sin que te bloquee la selección.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div id="wrapper" class="container">
  <form id="form1" name="formbusvet" action="php/busvet.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="pnombre">Primer Nombre</label>
          <input name="pnombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Nombre" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="snombre">Segundo Nombre</label>
          <input name="snombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundo Nombre" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="papellido">Primer Apellido</label>
          <input name="papellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Apellido" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="sapellido">Segundo Apellido</label>
          <input name="sapellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundo Apellido" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="clase">Clase</label>
          <input name="clase" class="form-control" placeholder="Clase" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="batalla">Batalla</label>
          <input name="batalla" class="form-control" placeholder="Batalla" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <label class="control-label" for="division">Divisi&oacute;n</label>
          <input name="division" class="form-control" placeholder="Divisi&oacute;n" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <label class="control-label" for="brigada">Brigada</label>
          <input name="brigada" class="form-control" placeholder="Brigada" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="unidad">Unidad</label>
          <input name="unidad" class="form-control" placeholder="Unidad" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="batallon">Batall&oacute;n</label>
          <input name="batallon" class="form-control" placeholder="Batall&oacute;n" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label class="control-label" for="compagnia">Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a</label>
          <input name="compagnia" class="form-control" placeholder="Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <div style="margin-top:15px">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Buscar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Correcto estas tapando un div con otros

Answer (score 1):

Solo se debe encerrar dentro de la clase form-group al grupo de un input y un label, aparte estás generando un div que cubre los demás, como lo mencionaron en otra respuesta:

```
<div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</div>
```

Este no parece ser necesario para que funcione. Te dejo el código corregido

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <form id="form1" name="formbusvet" action="php/busvet.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">        
            <label class="control-label" for="pnombre">Primer Nombre</label>
            <input name="pnombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Nombre" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="snombre">Segundo Nombre</label>
            <input name="snombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundo Nombre" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="papellido">Primer Apellido</label>
            <input name="papellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Apellido" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="sapellido">Segundo Apellido</label>
            <input name="sapellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundo Apellido" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="clase">Clase</label>
            <input name="clase" class="form-control" placeholder="Clase" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="batalla">Batalla</label>
            <input name="batalla" class="form-control" placeholder="Batalla" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <label class="control-label" for="division">Divisi&oacute;n</label>
            <input name="division" class="form-control" placeholder="Divisi&oacute;n" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <label class="control-label" for="brigada">Brigada</label>
            <input name="brigada" class="form-control" placeholder="Brigada" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="unidad">Unidad</label>
            <input name="unidad" class="form-control" placeholder="Unidad" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="batallon">Batall&oacute;n</label>
            <input name="batallon" class="form-control" placeholder="Batall&oacute;n" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="compagnia">Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a</label>
            <input name="compagnia" class="form-control" placeholder="Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a" type="text">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:15px">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Buscar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```